# Indoor training plan for 0-5k

Tags: training

Is it possible to get 0-5k training programme to do at home indoors?
I would like to start running but am nervous about starting my training outside in public when I can’t even run to the end of the road!

Comment: I don't have an actual answer for you, but all I can say is: just go for it! Being outside for exercise is infinitely better than inside. It will probably give you better motivation to finish the program. Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

I completely understand where you're coming from. If you're solely looking for an indoor workout plan, I'd highly recommend YouTube! For example, [HoyPro](https://www.youtube.com/user/yaboymillhoy) frequently posts great indoor workouts and has one specifically tailored towards [5k prep](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rtEQQiKcMLQ).

My personal favorite when it comes to getting motivated is the [Let's Inspire](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCdXqq7oafvJdL426exvhWtg) YouTube channel!

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

If you are specifically asking about something like "Couch to 5k", sort of? If you have enough room to do a loop in your house, or have a treadmill, there are plenty of programs out there. I'm a personal fan of the [Zombie Run 5k](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sixtostart.zombies5ktraining&hl=en_US&gl=US) app (also available on Apple), but it's not completely free (you get to experience the first 2-3 weeks free and then I think it's something like $5). I just like having a narrative to my running. In my opinion, this inside training doesn't quite teach you to actually run because your strides will be necessarily foreshortened, but it does a pretty decent job of getting your cardio up, particularly since most C25k programs are less about distance and more about time and effort.